# How to build a javascript class which accept a callback object

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose I want to create a javascript class/object/function which have a method that can accept a callback object like this:

```
callbacks = {
   onSuccess : // method to be executed in case of success
   onComplete : // method to be executed in case of complete
   onFailure : // method to be executed in case of failure
   onError : // method to be executed in case of an error
}
```

So let's suppose the classes name definition are the following:

```
var Obj = function () {};

Obj.prototype.exec = function (callbacks, event, caller, argument) {
}
```

And I want to use the object in this way:

```
var mytest = new Test();
var myObj = new Obj();
Obj.exec(callbacks,["onSuccess", "onComplete"], mytest, arguments);
```

How should Obj.prototype.exec be implemented?

Comment: Is `onSuccess` supposed to be one of those callbacks?

Comment: That is "An object" not "JSON".

Comment: Yes, onSuccess is supposed to be one of those callbacks. I corrected the callback object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little confusing what you are asking:

```
Obj.prototype.exec = function (callbacks, event, caller, argument) {
    var $xhr;
    if (argument instanceof Array)
        $xhr = caller.ajax.apply(this, argument)
    else
       $xhr = caller.ajax.call(this, argument)

    // wire up the listeners
    for (var i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
        $xhr[event[i]] = callbacks[event[i]];
    }

}
```

something like this perhaps